# Induced topology vs subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Reading my book I found this definition of an *induced topology*, which was then alleged to be equivalent to the standard definition of the *subspace topology* for that special case. However, I'm failing to see why they are equivalent. Can anyone help me here? Thanks!

[image: induced topology as defined in "Modern differential geometry for physicists" by Chris J Isham]

The equations cited in the text are:

[image: Cited equations]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $i: A \rightarrow X$ is the embedding map ($i(x) = x$ for $x \in A$), then for $O \subset X$ we have that $i^{-1}[O] = \{x \in A: i(x) \in O \} = \{x \in A: x \in O \} = O \cap A$. This explains the comment. The point is that the injective map is essentially the identity (to get the subspace topology).

Comment: Oh, yeah that was the missing bit. They didn't mention that that was the wanted map... That's also called the *inclusion map*, isn't it?

Comment: @guillefix Yes, it also called inclusion map.

Comment: Munkres might be a bit sloppy here IMHO, he says "an inclusion", not the inclusion map; but maybe he introduced this in an earlier section.